# Faye.js not working on Heroku with https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, faye

I am developing `rails 4 application` with `private_pub` for chatting apps. Its work perfect in local. But when move code from local to `Heroku` chatting not working due to below error:

```
https://XXXXXX-XXXXXXX-8XXX6.herokuapp.com/faye.js  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Actually in local working with `http://` and on `Heroku with https://` so may be issue but not found. Any one have a idea on it.

Thanks

Comment: assets precompile on heroku

Comment: Let me try. How to any idea?

Comment: `heroku run rake assets:clean` and then `heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a separated faye app on heroku? If not it's described here: http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/hello-or-building-a-chatting-app-with-rails/. Btw I changed from faye to pusher in which case I don't have to deploy a second app on heroku.

Comment: I Run it in local using "rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production" command so i have to Run this command on Heroku server ? How ?

Comment: Have you read the article? It's in the second part http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/deploying-private-pub-on-heroku/ But you should read the first part as well.